# Training SGDRegressor on a dataset in chunks

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

For a machine learning task I need to deal with quite large data sets. As a result, I cannot fit the entire data set at once in my algorithm. I am looking for a way to train my algorithm in parts on the data set, simply feeding new chunks won't work since my algorithm will just refit and not won't take the previous examples into account. Is there a method with which I can feed my algorithm new data, while "remembering" the previous data seen before?

Edit: The algorithm I use is the SGDRegressor from scikit-learn.

The code:

```
train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"Train.csv"),chunksize = 5000)
labels = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"Labels.csv"),chunksize = 5000)
algo = SGDRegressor(n_iter = 75)
print("looping for chunks in train")
for chunk in train:
    algo.fit(train,labels)
```

Comment: You'd better add some clarifications about algorithms you use, some snippets of working code, short and self contained are welcomed on SO. Currently this Q is way too broad, as not all ML techniques can be used incrementally.

Comment: I'll do it right now.

Comment: you could use a genetic algorithm ... where you just take random samples from your training set (you dont need to even look at the whole set) and an individuals chance of continuing on to the next generation is proportional to its fitness score ... (regardless of the other fitness scores in the set)

Comment: So have you read [the link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html) you've given in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442741/pandas-index-error)? It answers this question as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`partial_fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.partial_fit) to feed parts of training data to SGDRegressor.

See [sample code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html) in examples.